# Specifying grid width and height dimensions with ArcMap custom toolbox parameter

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, parameters, cell-size

I am using I am writing a script to create a tool (in ArcMap 10.7.1) that involves overlaying an agricultural field with a specific grid size. I need the grid to contain a custom width and height of the individual cells, as specified by the tool user. The input will look like this:

```
#User-defined input, stored as an integer
cellSize = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Generate grid
polygonWidth = cellSize
polygonHeight = cellSize
```

The grid will be generated with the `arcpy.GridIndexFeatures_cartography` tool.

What I don't know how to do is to add the measurement units to the end of the tool parameter. I want the numeric entry that my users provide to be followed by "feet."

When I upload my script to the toolbox, is there an option that will allow me to specify the measurement units, so that I will be able to generate a proper grid?

Comment: Use parameter type Linear Unit https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001500000035000000 to get your parameter(s) when you are adding your script to your toolbox, this will give you the option of metres, feet, inches, miles etc. in the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you mention in your question is [GridIndexFeatures_cartography](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00700000000q000000), looking at the tool help you will see that the parameters for the width and height:

> polygon_width (Optional) Width of the index polygon specifed in either
>   map or page units. If page units are being used the default value is 1
>   inch. If map units are being used the default is 1 degree.
>
> polygon_height (Optional) Height of the index polygon
>   specifed in either map or page units. If page units are being used the
>   default value is 1 inch. If map units are being used the default is 1
>   degree.

Are both of type `GPLinearUnit` which will accept a unit description like feet, metres, miles etc.. When you are [setting up your script](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) to run from a toolbox [specify the parameter type of Linear Unit](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001500000035000000) (a lot of text on this page, do a Ctrl + F and search for `GPLinearUnit`) for your first parameter, the value obtained from this script tool parameter can be passed directly into the call of GridIndexFeatures.